# SQLite search two tables

Tags: sqlite

In a SQLite database, I have created two tables:

```
CREATE Table Master (ItemID VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY, Property VARCHAR)
CREATE Table Counter (OtherID VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY, ItemID VARCHAR)
```

Records on table Master:
* ItemID: Book, Property: large
* ItemID: Table, Property: green

Records on table Counter:
* OtherID: random1, ItemID: Book
* OtherID: random2, ItemID: Book
* OtherID: random3, ItemID: Book

The column ItemID on table Master has the same contents as the same-named column on table Counter.

What is the correct SQL select statement to get all rows from table Master sorted by the number of their records in table Counter ?

In this case, row "Book" has three counts in table Counter and should be listed on first position, while row "Table" has no counts and should be the second result.

I know how to do this on one table but never managed to get a SQL select statement working that spans two tables.

Any help is appreciated.

By the way: I cannot change the table structure; so not sure if there would be something better, but I have to work with the tables as they are.

Comment: I just saw that I made a big mistake while describing my problem: Each table is located in its own database file... please excuse this oversight.

So not sure if there is a solution overall since JOIN (as I read in my SQLite docs) works only on tables part of the same database. Is this correct?

Comment: Can you make a [mcve] showing how you access both databases?

Answer (score 1):

- attach to two different databases
- access tables with "db?." in front
- join both tables on the common semantic, i.e. the ItemId
- left join to get the "empty" lines, too, with "0" count
- make groups which represent the lines you want in the output, i.e. also by ItemId
- grouping allows using the aggregate function "count()"
- order according to desired output, i.e. by count, but descending to get "3" first
- select the ItemId and the property to match desired output

Code:

```
attach 'master.db' as dbm;
attach 'counter.db' as dbc;
select a.ItemId, property
from dbm.Master a LEFT JOIN dbc.Counter b 
using (ItemId) 
group by a.ItemId 
order by count(OtherId) desc;
```

Tested with :

```
echo .dump | sqlite3 counter.db

BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE Counter (OtherID VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY, ItemID VARCHAR);
INSERT INTO Counter VALUES('random1','book');
INSERT INTO Counter VALUES('random2','book');
INSERT INTO Counter VALUES('random3','book');
COMMIT;

echo .dump | sqlite3 master.db

BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE Master (ItemID VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY, Property VARCHAR);
INSERT INTO Master VALUES('book','large');
INSERT INTO Master VALUES('table','green');
COMMIT;
```

Output:

```
book|large
table|green
```

Comment: Thank you. This works well if both tables are located within the same database. Unfortunately, I forgot to mention (sorry for this mistake) that each table is located in its own database file. Not sure if this makes it possible overall to get a solution...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you, I think this should work:

```
SELECT M.ItemId, Property 
FROM Master M 
LEFT JOIN Counter C 
ON M.itemid=C.itemid 
GROUP BY C.itemid 
ORDER BY COUNT(C.itemid) DESC;
```